# php function not executing

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php code where i am calling a function dataLC() to update some values, but as soon as the page executes, the function calling part didn't execute, I am unable to figure out the problem--

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$GLOBALS['lks']=0;
$GLOBALS['cmnts']=0;

echo $GLOBALS['lks'];
echo $GLOBALS['cmnts'];
?>
<div class="btnclasess">
          <div id="likescommentID" class="likescomment"><?php dataLC(2); ?><a style="padding-right: 7px" href="#"><?php if($GLOBALS['lks']==0){echo '';}else{ echo $GLOBALS['lks']." Likes"; } ?></a><a href="#"><?php if($GLOBALS['cmnts']==0){echo '';}else{ echo $GLOBALS['cmnts']." Comments"; } ?></a></div>
         <div class="pull-left likebtn"><a href="#" onClick="connect(2)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="margin-right: 6px;"></i>Like</a></div>
         <button class="pull-left btnhideshow show_hide" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2"><li class="fa fa-comments show_hide" style="margin-right: 6px;"></li>Comment</button>
         <button class="pull-left btnhideshow show_hide"><li class="fa fa-share-alt show_hide" style="margin-right: 6px;"></li>Share</button>
         <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<script>
        function connect(num) {

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "user-likes.php?id="+num,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#likescommentID").load(" #likescommentID");
    }
    });
    }
</script>
<?php 
function dataLC($val)
{
    $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select likes,comments from user_posts where slno=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $val);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($lksD,$cmntsD);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    $GLOBALS['lks']=$lksD;
    $GLOBALS['cmnts']=$cmntsD;
}
?>
```

Can anyone pls check why the function dataLC() call is not working.

Comment: Where is `$linkID1` defined? You should be using error reporting.

Comment: in include 'db.php';

Comment: scope issues then

Comment: Please add that code. I think that would be out of scope, have you enabled error reporting?

Comment: Looks like a variable scope issue

Comment: can you provide `db.php` after removing the credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the database variable as a parameter instead. The variable `$linkID1` does not exist in the function.

Pass it as a parameter :

```
function dataLC($linkID1 , $val) {

}
```

Comment: Pleasure friend!

Answer (score 0):

I think in `db.php` there a connection class and `$linkID1` is an object. If this statement is true then maybe you missed the object initialization for this page, Try to use reinitiation for this object.

like ie. `$linkID1  = new classname( constructor parameters);`